# Build a fixed-size data table with tkinter / tksheet in Python -- bug in sheet_display_dimensions

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a user interface with several (as many as the user wants) tabular (spreadsheet-like) forms of user-specified size (but the size won't change once initialized). The user populates these tables either by copy-pasting data (usually from excel) or directly typing data to the cells. I am using the Tksheet Tkinter add-on.
It seems that there are several options in Tksheet to achieve the goal of opening an empty table of i rows and j columns:

a) `set_sheet_data_and_display_dimensions(total_rows = None, total_columns = None)`.

This routine throws a TypeError. The error is raised in:
`GetLinesHeight(self, n, old_method = False)` 
The subroutine expects the parameter n to be an integer, but receives a tuple.
The calling routine is `sheet_display_dimensions`, and the relevant line is:
`height = self.MT.GetLinesHeight(self.MT.default_rh)`.

`MT.default_rh` is apparently a complex object, it *can* be an integer, but also a string or a tuple. Other routines that use it in Tksheet perform elaborate manipulation to make sure it is handed to the subroutine in integer form, but not so `sheet_display_dimensions`.

b) `sheet_data_dimensions(total_rows = None, total_columns = None)`

This seems to work programmatically, but does not display the table to the user.
One may add the line `sheet_display_dimensions(i,j)` but--you guessed it--this raises an error...

Sample code:

```
from tksheet import Sheet
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# This class builds and displays a test table. It is not part of the question but merely used to illustrate it
class SeriesTable(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)  # call super class init to build frame
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # This configures the window's escalators
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
        self.sheet = Sheet(self, data=[[]])  # set up empty table inside the frame
        self.sheet.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
        self.sheet.enable_bindings(bindings=  # enable table behavior
                                   ("single_select",
                                    "select_all",
                                    "column_select",
                                    "row_select",
                                    "drag_select",
                                    "arrowkeys",
                                    "column_width_resize",
                                    "double_click_column_resize",
                                    "row_height_resize",
                                    "double_click_row_resize",
                                    "right_click_popup_menu",
                                    "rc_select",  # rc = right click
                                    "copy",
                                    "cut",
                                    "paste",
                                    "delete",
                                    "undo",
                                    "edit_cell"
                                    ))
        # Note that options that change the structure/size of the table (e.g. insert/delete col/row) are disabled

        # make sure that pasting data won't change table size
        self.sheet.set_options(expand_sheet_if_paste_too_big=False)
        # bind specific events to my own functions
        self.sheet.extra_bindings("end_edit_cell", func=self.cell_edited)
        self.sheet.extra_bindings("end_paste", func=self.cells_pasted)
        label = "Change column name"  # Add option to the right-click menu for column headers
        self.sheet.popup_menu_add_command(label, self.column_header_change, table_menu=False, index_menu=False, header_menu=True)

    # Event functions
    def cell_edited(self, info_tuple):
        r, c, key_pressed, updated_value = info_tuple  # break the info about the event to individual variables
        '''
        updated_value checked here
        '''
        # passed tests
        pass  # go do stuff

    def cells_pasted(self, info_tuple):
        key_pressed, rc_tuple, updated_array = info_tuple  # break the info about the event to individual variables
        r, c = rc_tuple  # row & column where paste begins
        err_flag = False  # will be switched if errors are encountered
        '''
        updated_array is checked here
        '''
        # passed tests
        if err_flag:  # error during checks is indicated
            self.sheet.undo()  # undo change
        else:
            pass  # go do stuff

    def column_header_change(self):
        r, c = self.sheet.get_currently_selected()
        col_name = sd.askstring("User Input", "Enter column name:")
        if col_name is not None and col_name != "":  # if user cancelled (or didn't enter anything), do nothing
            self.sheet.headers([col_name], index=c)  # This does not work - it always changes the 1st col
            self.sheet.redraw()


# from here down is test code
tk_win = tk.Tk()  # establish the root tkinter window
tk_win.title("Master Sequence")
tk_win.geometry("600x400")
tk_win.config(bg='red')
nb = ttk.Notebook(tk_win)  # a notebook in ttk is a [horizontal] list of tabs, each associated with a page
nb.pack(expand=True, fill='both')  # widget packing strategy
settings_page = tk.Frame(nb)  # initiate 1st tab object in the notebook
nb.add(settings_page, text = "Settings")  # add it as top page in the notebook
test = SeriesTable(nb)  # creates a 1 row X 0 column table
nb.add(test, text = "Table Test")  # add it as second page in the notebook
i = 4
j = 3
#test.sheet.set_sheet_data_and_display_dimensions(total_rows=i, total_columns=j)  # raises TypeError
#test.sheet.sheet_data_dimensions(total_rows=i, total_columns=j)  # extends the table to 4 X 3, but the display is still 1 X 0
#test.sheet.sheet_display_dimensions(total_rows=i, total_columns=j)   # raises TypeError
test.sheet.insert_columns(j)  # this works
test.sheet.insert_rows(i - 1)  # note that we insert i-1 because table already has one row
test.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a work-around with:
c)

```
insert_columns(j)
insert_rows(i - 1)
```

Note that you have to insert i-1 rows. This is because the sheet object is initiated with 1 row and 0 columns. (But does it say so in the documentation? No it does not...)